# Proof that $\text{dim cokernel}(g\circ f)\leq \text{dim cokernel}(f)+\text{dim cokernel}(g)$

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to proof that the composition of two fredholm operators is again a fredholm operator.
Let $f:H\rightarrow H'$ and $g:H'\rightarrow H''$ be two Fredholm operators, that means $f$ and $g$ are linear maps and $\text{kernel}(f),\text{cokernel}(f),\text{kernel}(g),\text{cokernel}(g)$ are all finite dimensional.

I want to prove that $g\circ f$ is a fredholm operator, too.
Proofing that $\text{kernel}(g\circ f)$ is finite dimensional is easy via the inequality $\text{dim kernel}(g\circ f)\leq \text{dim kernel}(g)+\text{dim kernel}(f)$
One can use the dimension formula to proof this.

Now I need to proof that $\text{dim cokernel}(g\circ f)$ is also finite dimensional via the inequality $\text{dim cokernel}(g\circ f)\leq \text{dim cokernel}(f)+\text{dim cokernel}(g)$

My problem is that I don´t know how to show the last inequality.

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: If you can prove your result for the kernel, it suffices to apply your result to the adjoint $(g \circ f)^* = f^* \circ g^*$. Note that there is a natrual identification between $\ker(f^*)$ and the dual space of $\text{coker}(f)$.

Comment: By these inequalities, do you rather mean their dimensions satisfy these inequalities?

Comment: Yes I meant their dimensions. Thanks I just edited it.

Comment: @Ben Großmann Thank you for your answer. I know that $\text{ker}(f)$ is isomorph to $(\text{coker}(f))*$ if the the Vectorspaces H and H' are finite dimensional, but in this case they can also be infinite dimensional.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a proof that $\text{coker}(f)^* \cong \ker f^*$.

Define $\Phi:\text{coker}(f)^* \to \ker f^*$ as follows: for $\alpha \in \text{coker}(f)^*$ and $x \in H$,
$$
\Phi(\alpha)(x) = \alpha(x + \text{ran}(f))
$$
To see that $\Phi$ indeed maps elements to $\ker f^*$, note that
$$
f^*(\Phi(\alpha))(x) = (\Phi(\alpha) \circ f)(x) = \Phi(\alpha)(f(x)) = \alpha(f(x) + \text{ran}(f)) = \alpha(0) = 0
$$
To see that $\Phi$ is injective, we note that
$$
\Phi(\alpha) = 0 \implies\\
\alpha(x + \text{ran}(f)) = 0\quad  \text{ for all }x \implies\\
\alpha = 0.
$$
To see that $\Phi$ is surjective, consider any $\beta \in \ker f^*$. We note that for all $x$, we have
$$
f^*(\beta)(x) = 0 \implies \beta(f(x)) = 0,
$$
so that $\text{ran}(f) \subset \ker \beta$. It follows that the induced map $\tilde \beta :H/\text{ran}(f) \to \Bbb C$ is well defined, and $\Phi(\tilde \beta) = \beta$.

Comment: Thank you two very much. I got it now :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also show this directly:

If $f\colon H_1 \to H_2$ and $g \colon H_2 \to H_3$ and both have finite-dimensional cokernels, then $H_2/f(H_1)$ is finite dimensional and so is $H_3/g(H_2)$. But then we have $g(f(H_1) \subseteq g(H_2) \subseteq H_3$, so that $\dim(H_3/g(f(H_1))) = \dim(H_3/g(H_2)) + \dim(g(H_2)/g(f(H_1))$

Now $\dim(\text{coker}(g)) = \dim(H_3/g(H_2)$ and if $\bar{g} \colon H_2/f(H_1) \to H_3/g(f(H_2)$ is the linear map induced by $g$ on $H_2/f(H_1)$, then $g(H_2)/g(f(H_1))$ is precisely the image of $H_2/f(H_1)$ under $\bar{g}$, and hence $\dim(g(H_2)/g(f(H_1))\leq \dim(H_2/g(f(H_2)))$